# Magento 2.4 Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter required of class TemplateFactory

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4

In Magento 2.4.5 error Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #3 [  ] of class Magento\Email\Model\TemplateFactory;

Class not found?

Comment: This error is almost always due to the lack of the classes that Magento removed when upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Change class:

```
use Magento\Email\Model\TemplateFactory;
```

To

```
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\FactoryInterface;
```